# SQL Query non naming complete database name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a set of tables that are exactly the same but changing the first value only, its a date value like this:

```
dbo.[2016_09_06_CHEQ]
```

so instead of writing the same query but changing the date in the name is there a way to search all over the tables?? something like this?

```
dbo.[*_CHEQUES]??
```

is there a way to do this? or how can i archive something like this on my statement

Comment: Yes, dynamic SQL. Check this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx
Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: yes im using sql server

Comment: Arturo, there are several answers for your question. Did anyone work? If it did, you should mark one as accepted, out of respect for those who took the time to reply.

Comment: yes srry, i got it working thanks to Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to do it with a cursor:

```
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  

    SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_CHEQUES'

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @tableName  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    SET @query = @query + 'SELECT CommonField1, CommonField2 FROM ' + @tableName + ' WHERE CommonField3 = value '

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @tableName  
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
--      SET @query = @query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'UNION ALL ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) -- To add line breaks for easier reading when debugging
        SET @query = @query + 'UNION ALL '
END  

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

--PRINT @query -- To debug the result query
EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
declare @q nvarchar(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM '

;with cte as (
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
AND table_name like '%_CHEQ'
)
select @q = @q + '[' + table_name + '] UNION SELECT * FROM ' FROM cte

SET @q = SUBSTRING(@q, 1, LEN(@q) - 19)
EXEC sp_executesql @q
```

Comment: In order to avoid repeating the selected fields (imagine they are 10 fields and not just `*`), I would initialize `@q = ''` and then do `select @q = @q + ' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM [' + table_name + ']' FROM cte` and `SET @q = SUBSTRING(@q, 12, LEN(@q))`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using SQL Server.
You can use the undocumented procedure sp_MSforeachtable with this sys stored procedure you can retrieve all information from your tables using a single statement

```
USE YOUR_DATABASE GO EXEC master.sys.sp_MSforeachtable @command1="SELECT * FROM ?"
```

This statement runs a SELECT in each table present in your database.
Also you can use a Dynamic Query

```
    DECLARE @name varchar(400),
@sql varchar(4000)

SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1(name) FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'U' and name like '%CHEQ%' ORDER BY name)
WHILE @name IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT @sql = 'SELECT * FROM [dbo].['+@name+']'
    EXEC(@sql)
    PRINT 'TABLE PROCESSED: '+@name
    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1(name) FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'U' AND name > @name ORDER BY name)
END
GO
```

Comment: I think you still need the `like` in the last `SELECT`. One downside of this approach is that you are doing multiple queries instead of one to get all the tables and one to query them all. In this case it's harmless, but bear in mind that EXEC is prone to SQL injection, so never use it with use input.